# How to add style rules to print.css

Tags: magento2, css, rwd, less

In M2 they use custom [.media-width mixin rules](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd-breakpoints.html) to add to styles-m.css or styles-l.css.

```
//
//  Common
//  _____________________________________________
& when (@media-common = true) {
   .catalog-product-view {

   }
}

//
//  Mobile
//  _____________________________________________
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {

}

//
//  Desktop
//  _____________________________________________
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {

}
```

Is there a similar method for adding style rules to print.css?

Comment: Yes you can use similar way, but extend your print.less and keep original file , you can make addition but do not remove original styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[print.less](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/print.less) file is used for print styles:

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/print.less
```

So you should just need to extend/overwrite this file in your theme.

More info found on the dev docs here - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

Answer (score 4):

If you use a custom theme you can go to the theme's path:

`app/design/frontend/YourVendorName/YourThemeName/web/css` and do a file called `print.less`.

Into that file copy and paste the content from this file:
 `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/print.less`.

After that add the style changes that you want to do in `app/design/frontend/YourVendorName/YourThemeName/web/css/print.less` and then run this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The static-content deploy command is only required when running in production mode btw.

Comment: I'm running in developer mode and the print.less in my theme doesn't get processed unless I run deploy  : (

Comment: Solution is not working